# Add Column to csv osx

Tags: macos, csv, awk, automation

Recently I've switched from windows to osx and I'm struggling to work out the best way to automate some tasks I used to use Windows Power Shell for.

In power shell I used to run a script to add & populate columns in a csv file

```
Import-Csv z:\myfile.csv | Select-Object @{Name='ACTION';Expression={''}},*,@{Name='COUNTRY';Expression={'UNITED KINGDOM'}} | Export-Csv z:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

As you can see this adds 2 columns to the csv and populates Country with United Kingdom.

I also used to run this from a batch file which would create folders with the date & place the created files in before deleting the original file.

My question is what's the best / most efficient way to achieve this in osx?

I have looked and think it maybe awk, I have tried with automator but haven't had much success.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Powershell is not really that well represented on SO, and it seems most answerers cast their replies in BATCH... that being the case, you may do better to show how your file looks before and after the process, as everybody on here can relate to that. In general on OSX, Automator and Applescript are very verbose, and I would recommend you use `bash`, `awk`, `sed` and maybe `Perl` as those skills are transportable to Linux as well as OSX. Anyway, show a before and after and I am sure someone will help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 1st line is header, if not remove heading `1!`

```
sed '1!s/$/,,UNITED KINGDOM/' z:\myfile.csv > z:\output.csv
```

it add to end of each line, except 1st, the trailing `,,UNITED KINGDOM`

Comment: I see, is it possible to make the header COUNTRY then fill the values of UNITED KINGDOM? or does this take 2 commands?

Comment: could make at least 2 actions in same sed command. Here it keep header and add UNITED at end of other line